# Help me to identify these two trees in my back yard?

Tags: identification, trees

I have two trees in my backyard that I need help identifying. My home is in Port Saint Lucie, which is on the eastern coast of the southern half of Florida.  Hardiness zone 10a. My home backs into a drainage canal, and the two trees are on the edge of the canal:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I added a picture from your drive. The acorn is an unmistakable sign of an oak. There are many oaks that grow in Florida but the shiny leaves without lobes indicate to me that this is a [live oak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_oak) (Quercus virginia) as described [here](http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/pdffiles/FR/FR00400.pdf)

> Unlike most other oaks, the live oak retains its  leaves until after
>   the following year's leaves have  appeared. This habit results in an
>   "evergreen" tree.  Leaves are unlobed and rarely toothed: lustrous
>   green  above and pale-pubescent on the underside. Leaf  length varies
>   from 2-to-5 inches with width ranging  from 1/2-to-2-1/2 inches.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to check out the live oaks in the area and compare.  Most of them in the area are very large, so I didn't consider it.  The two trees are different species.  Any idea what it may be?

Comment: No, the acorns are way wrong. I was looking at *Quercus incana*, *Quercus laurifolia*, etc etc...

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a young [water oak (Quercus nigra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_nigra).